# Keyboard "done" button pressed event for UIWebView and WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

There are resources for this when using UITextView. How do I register for the `Done` key button press event? The keyboard shows up when the user focuses a form inside the webview.

Answer (score 6):

The main idea is to use Javascript injection to achieve what you want.
You can try catching the DOM event called `onfocusout` (Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp for more details).

Following is the example of how you could do it for UIWebView. WKWebView can be handled in a similar way.

Call this to inject some Javascript code after the first time your webview loaded

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('youTextFieldID').addEventListener('onfocusout', function () {"
                                                @"var frame = document.createElement('iframe');"
                                                @"frame.src = 'doneEditing://';"
                                                @"document.body.appendChild(frame);"
                                                @"setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(frame); }, 0);"
                                                @"}, false);"];
```

Write your UIWebView delegate method like this

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"doneEditing"]) {
            // Call you event handler here
            [self doneButtonTouchEventHandler]
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The key is to add event listeners when the web page loads. I assume that you want to know about the `blur` event of a text field.

**Here is a basic working example:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function initPage() {
        document.addEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn);
        document.addEventListener('focusout', handleFocusOut);
    }

    function handleFocusIn(e) {
        alert('In');
    }

    function handleFocusOut(e) {
        alert('Out');
    }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initPage()">

<form>
    <input type="text" name="username">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps, please let me know otherwise!

Good luck!

Comment: I think he is asking for objetive-c lenguaje

Answer (score 0):

@Ducky
 answers is for UIWebView

here is a solution for WkWebview

extend ViewController as WKNavigationDelegate

```
 webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

implement and override function
get your button id and write on  document.getElementById
this method called on page load finish

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("loaded")

                let doneJS = """
    document.getElementById('m_ara_input').addEventListener('focusout', function () {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.src = 'doneEditing://';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(frame); }, 0);
    }, false);
    """

                webView.evaluateJavaScript(doneJS, completionHandler: nil)


}
```

override below method

```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {return}


        if (url.scheme == "doneediting") {

             executeSubmit()

         }


        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

write this function

```
    func executeSubmit(){

        let js = """
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default pull-left");
a.ara_buton.click();
"""
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

in javascript  `ara_buton`  is the attribute of "name" of button